# Finding given circle point on a square behind (Minimap)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, trigonometry

I need formula of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039873/given-a-point-on-a-circle-find-it-on-a-given-square) calculation in Unity3d/C#, but i am a little bit dumb to do it by myself. I already have the circle with point and coordinates on it. I need to calculate distance to cube edges.

I tried to do it using chatGPT, but it didn't worked. ChatGPT calculations on y axes are wrong.

[Image of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mn2L.png)

ChatGPT code

```
public static Vector2 ConvertPointOnCircleToNearestPointOnSquare(Vector2 circleCenter, float circleRadius, Vector2 circlePoint)
    {
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(circlePoint.y - circleCenter.y, circlePoint.x - circleCenter.x);

        // find the closest side of the square
        float sideX, sideY;
        if (angle >= -Mathf.PI / 4 && angle < Mathf.PI / 4)
        {
            // right
            sideX = circleCenter.x + circleRadius;
            sideY = circleCenter.y + (circleRadius / Mathf.Tan(angle));
        }
        else if (angle >= Mathf.PI / 4 && angle < 3 * Mathf.PI / 4)
        {
            // top
            sideX = circleCenter.x + (circleRadius / Mathf.Tan(angle));
            sideY = circleCenter.y + circleRadius;
        }
        else if (angle >= -3 * Mathf.PI / 4 && angle < -Mathf.PI / 4)
        {
            // bottom
            sideX = circleCenter.x - (circleRadius / Mathf.Tan(angle));
            sideY = circleCenter.y - circleRadius;
        }
        else
        {
            // left
            sideX = circleCenter.x - circleRadius;
            sideY = circleCenter.y - (circleRadius / Mathf.Tan(angle));
        }

        // find the coordinates of the nearest point on the side of the square
        float distanceX = Mathf.Abs(sideX - circlePoint.x);
        float distanceY = Mathf.Abs(sideY - circlePoint.y);
        float squareX, squareY;
        if (distanceX < distanceY)
        {
            squareX = sideX;
            squareY = circlePoint.y > circleCenter.y ? circleCenter.y + circleRadius : circleCenter.y - circleRadius;
        }
        else
        {
            squareX = circlePoint.x > circleCenter.x ? circleCenter.x + circleRadius : circleCenter.x - circleRadius;
            squareY = sideY;
        }

        return new Vector2(squareX, squareY);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose r is radiuse of circle and point P on circle was on position (x,y) then you can get the projection point on square (Q) in unity by below formula:

```
    float alpha = Mathf.Atan2(y, x);
    float xQ = r * Mathf.Max(-1, Mathf.Min(1.0f/Mathf.Tan(alpha), 1)) * Mathf.Sign(Mathf.Sin(alpha));
    float yQ = r * Mathf.Max(-1, Mathf.Min(Mathf.Tan(alpha), 1)) * Mathf.Sign(Mathf.Cos(alpha));
    Vector2 Q = new Vector2(xQ, yQ);
```